# Counting number of objects in a Parse Class and assign it to a variable

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, notifications

I want to retrive the number of objects in a class, then display that number on a badge.

Problem is that if I write `self.totalMessagesInMesagesCount = count` I got this error: **Cannot assign a value of type 'Int32?' to a value of type 'Int'** when assigning that variable to `applicationIconBadgeNumber`

so I have:

```
var totalMessagesInMesagesCount : Int!
```

then:

```
//MARK: this requires permission for notifications
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Sound | UIUserNotificationType.Alert |
            UIUserNotificationType.Badge, categories: nil
            ))
        //MARK: this sets the number displayed in the red badge
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = totalMessagesInMesagesCount
```

finally I'd like to retrive the number and put it inside a variable

```
func loadMessagesByObjectData() {

        var findTimeLineDataQuery = PFQuery(className: KeyWords.ParseClassForPublicMessages)

        findTimeLineDataQuery.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (count: Int32, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                print("there are \(count) messages")
self.totalMessagesInMesagesCount = //what? count is not working

            }
        }


    }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide evidence that you are debugging.  Prove to the readers here that the count returned from the countObjects call doesn't agree with the number of objects in the class.

Comment: the problem in not about not matching numbers. Problem is that if I write `self.totalMessagesInMesagesCount = count` I got `Cannot assign a value of type 'Int32?' to a value of type 'Int'`  when assigning that variable to `applicationIconBadgeNumber `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the variable `totalMessagesInMesagesCount` is from type `Int`, while the variable `count` is `Int32` type. So simple solve it by casting like this:

```
    self.totalMessagesInMesagesCount = Int(count)
```

Comment: you are absolutely right, in my mind was wrong casting from a greater type to a smaller one

Comment: @biggreentree please write a new question and paste the link here, i will be   happy to help

Comment: Thank you, I'll clean up both question and comments! here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319345/parse-how-to-count-put-in-array-then-show-the-content-of-count